# log transformation logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, data-transformation, back-transformation

I have a logistic regression in which i transformed geographical distance measured in km using a natural log.

I've have run the regression, and now i am having trouble how to interpret the findings. I have found a b-value of .21 and an odds ratio of 1.23 (it is statistically significant) Do i need to convert these to orginial values using e^x? or do i need to do something different?

Also would it be better to use log10?

Thanks for your time

Comment: I would look at the z-statistic and associated P-value to test against the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you i have done that, it is statistically significant. i'm having troubles relating to the above question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to interpret it is to plot the predicted probabilities as a function of distance on the original scale, with confidence bands.  The following would do this using the R `rms` package:

```
dd <- datadist(mydata); options(datadist='dd')
f <- lrm(y ~ log(distance), data=mydata)
ggplot(Predict(f))
```

To make the fit more flexible (assuming the sample size supports this) use a restricted cubic spline in the distance:

```
f <- lrm(y ~ rcs(distance, 5), data=mydata)
```

Comment: Thank you plotting would be something i should do. However, i also need to show a clear explaination, for example an increase in 1 km or increase in 10 times the km increases the odds by x. Now, i can only state that 1 unit increase in ln geographical distance increses the odds by 1.23, this does not say much. Thank you

Comment: If log distance is a predictor, then the equivalent effect in distance terms will depend on distance. You can get that graphically but it can't be boiled down to a single number. It works both ways: the transformation from distance to log distance is nonlinear and so is the inverse or back transformation.

Comment: It's the odds ratio for a change in distance by a factor of 2.71..., which I suppose would be an argument for a log10 so that it would be for being 10 times as distant.

Comment: @Björn On the contrary, common logs are awful for this purpose. The advantage of natural logs is their relationship to simple proportional changes when the changes are small. In this case, because $\log(1.23)=0.21=b$, we see immediately, using the simplest mental arithmetic, that a $10\%$ increase in distance increases the odds by $10\%\times b = 2.1\%$. That is, multiplying a distance by $1.10$ multiplies the odds by $1.021$.  ($10\%$ is a reasonable value to use for a "small" change because $\exp(10\%)\approx 1.10$ and that approximation rapidly degrades for larger changes.)